# load jquery modal dialog after a delay

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui-dialog

I would like to load jquery dialog after a delay of few seconds after page load. Here is my code so far.

```
<div id="dialog" title="My Dialog Title" style="display:none">
<p>This is My Dialog box Description/Content</p>
```

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {    
    setTimeout(function(){
      $(function () {
        $("#dialog").dialog({
            show: {
            effect: 'drop',
            direction : 'up',
            distance: 1000,
            duration: 2000,
            },
        });
      });
    }, 2000)
});


</script>

    <style>
.ui-dialog-titlebar {display:none;}
#other_content {width:200px; height:200px;background-color:grey;}
#dialog_content{display:none;}
</style>
```

The problem is now that the popup animation of sliding from top is good for Chrome but in firefox it does not come to the center of the screen and for IE there is no popup at all.

http://jsfiddle.net/fakhruddin/x39Rr/9/

Please guide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `setTimeout()` to delay.

```
$(document).ready(function() {    
    setTimeout(function(){

        $("#dialog").dialog({
            show: {
            effect: 'fade',
            duration: 800,
            },
        });

    }, 2000)
});
```

Comment: I have already tried it, after implementing it does not even show the dialog it just shows the plain text on the window.

Comment: It works. You forget to include jQuery & jQueryUI in optoins. Check [link](http://jsfiddle.net/x39Rr/5/)

Comment: oh yes sorry my mistake...also how can I make it load from top to center of the window. I mean slide it from top of the window to the center position.

Comment: also I dont want the plain text to be visible on the screen before the dialog loads. Is there any way i can hide it...

Comment: for sliding configure dialog this way: `$("#dialog").dialog({
            show: {
            effect: 'drop',
            direction : 'up',
            duration: 800,
            },
        });`

Comment: @FakhruddinUjjainwala add style="display: none;" to the div

Comment: thats perfect...is it possible to load it from top of the window...i mean extreme top...

Comment: Yes you can use the dialog's positioning option at: 'bottom', my: 'top', of: 'window'

Comment: I am unable to get it proper can you please update it in code...or if you can give me a proper code for the same.

Comment: the popup window doesn't show up in IE  and in firefox it remains on the top of window doesn't come to the center.what could be the reason?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(function(){
 $('yourDiv').dialog({
   autoOpen: false
 });
});

function openMyDialog(){
 $('yourDiv').dialog('open');
}

$(document).ready(function(){
 setTimeout(function(){
    openMyDialog();}, 2000);
});
```

You can use the jquery slidedown/slideup: http://api.jquery.com/slideUp/

Comment: I have already tried it, after implementing it does not even show the dialog it just shows the plain text on the window.