# Set delay time in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup

I have a welcome popup on my home page site.

I have this Javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#div-welcome").dialog({
              width: 'auto',
              height: 'auto',
              modal: true
        });
    });
</script>
```

How can I set a delay of 3 seconds? I tried with setTime function but that didn't work. Maybe I put it in the wrong place.
Thank you!
AVersa

Comment: similar question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17305879/load-jquery-modal-dialog-after-a-delay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    window.setTimeout(function () {
        $("#div-welcome").dialog({
              width: 'auto',
              height: 'auto',
              modal: true
        });
    }, 3000);
});
```

Comment: Np! :) By the way, please accept an answer if you're satisfied.

Answer (score 1):

Use `setTimeout`.

The `setTimeout()` method calls a function or evaluates an expression after a specified number of milliseconds.

Write this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    setTimeout(function(){
        $("#div-welcome").dialog({
            width: 'auto',
            height: 'auto',
            modal: true
        });
    },3000);
});
```